# How to Find "n" for n-th Triangular Number

Tags: formatting, algebra

For example, the 7th triangular number is 28. How do I create something that will tell me that 28 is the 7th triangular number?

This is what I have created.

```
nthtri := Part[Solve[x^2 + x - (2 #) == 0, x], 2] &
```

This is what happens when executed.

```
nthtri[28]
```

returns

```
{x -> 7}
```

This newly defined function solves for the two roots of the quadratic equation. Since *Mathematica* lists the roots in increasing order, and since there are only two roots (one negative, one positive), by taking the 2nd root, you will find the "n" for a particular triangular number.

I think my current method is unprofessional and inelegant. **How do I create a function that will return a singular output value?** For example, I would like

```
nthtri[28]
```

to return

```
7
```

---

Edit: As suggested below by @Guesswhoitis, using `Root` works.

```
nthtri := Root[x^2 + x - (2 #), 2] &
```

But I am still looking for more solution methods. I got lucky that solving for triangular numbers involves a quadratic equation that strictly has one positive and one negative root. If it were in a different case, for instance with a cubic formula where no such root signs are guaranteed, `Root` would not be able to consistently generate correct answers.

Comment: Look up `ReplaceAll`. Alternatively, just use `Root[]`.

Comment: How would I use that here? What am I looking to replace?

Comment: You noticed that the output of your function is a `Rule`, yes? What's on the left?

Comment: A curly bracket. Sorry, I'm trying but failing to see how `ReplaceAll` works.

Comment: Well, yes, because it's a list, but I was telling you to look at the `Rule` object. What's on the left?

Comment: The variable `x` then, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25317/discussion-between-guess-who-it-is-and-a-is-for-ambition).

Comment: I'm lazy:  `x /. nthtri[28]` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comment and your own implementation with [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) it is better to define this:

```
nthtri[t_] := Root[#^2 + # - 2 t &, 2]

nthtri[28]
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

This has no unlocalized Symbols as your own version had.  With your code if you set `x = 5` before using it it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

f is the function you are looking for:

```
f[k_] := (1/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8*k]);
t[n_] := (1/2)*n*(1 + n);
Table[f[t[k]], {k, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: By any chance, did this involve simplifying the `+` case for the quadratic formula?

Comment: That would be it, yes.

Comment: Yes you can do:  `Solve[k == Expand[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]i\)], n]`

Answer (score 2):

Why not replace `#` with `n` and take second part as your function?

```
(x /. Solve[x (x + 1)/2 == n, x])[[2]]

(*1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])*)

f[n_] := 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])

f@28

(*7*)

With[{nn = 4}, Plot[f@x, {x, 0, # (# + 1)/2 &@nn}, Epilog -> {Red, 
PointSize[Medium], Point[Transpose@{# (# + 1)/2 & /@ Range@nn, Range@nn}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $t, n$ are the triangular number and its position, then you want $n(n+1) = 2t$

Completing the square

$n^2 + n + \frac{1}{4} = 2t + \frac{1}{4}$

and solving for positive n:

$n = \sqrt{2t + \frac{1}{4}} - \frac{1}{2}$

```
nthtri[t_] := Sqrt[2*t + 0.25] - 0.5;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to display your solution in Mathematica format.